Homology of punctured non-oriented surfaces
Computing recursively the homology of real oriented topological surfaces, I had to compute the homology of the punctured torus : $\mathbb{T}^2 \smallsetminus \{*\}$. It is rather visual that such a space is homotopy-equivalent to a wedge to two circles. Having that, we can compute the homology of $\mathbb{T}^2 \# \mathbb{T}^2 \# ... \# \mathbb{T}^2$ easily.
Is there a way to do the same thing is non-oriented surfaces and the punctured real projective plane, first: is there a more appealing space to which $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2 \smallsetminus \{*\}$ is homotopy-equivalent?
I wonder then if I could compute the homology of non-oriented the same way as for oriented ones.

Here they give an explicit deformation of $\Bbb {RP}^n\setminus{*}$ onto $\Bbb {RP}^{n-1}$.

I think that you should replace the word "pointed" with "punctured".  A "pointed space" is widely used to mean a pair $(X, x_0)$ where $X$ is a space and $x_0$ is a chosen point of $X$ (often used for things like 'computing the fundamental group at $x_0$"). A "punctured" space is often used to mean a space with a single point deleted, as in your question.

OK, thanks for the info!

I think this is not a duplicate of the linked question: the linked question is about punctured $n$-dimensional real projective space, while this question is about punctured non-orientable surfaces (see first sentence of second paragraph). $2$-dimensional real projective space is an example, but it is not the only example. Perhaps some minor editing would clarify this: change the title and change "that is to say" to "for example" in the second paragraph.

Exercise 7-14 in Jack Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds says: "Let $M$ be a compact connected surface that is not homeomorphic to $S^2$. Show that there is a point $p \in M$ such that $M\setminus\{p\}$ is homotopy equivalent to a bouquet of circles." (And if you view a point as the bouquet of no circles, then this is also true for $S^2$.)
